# Problem accessing JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

I am querying the LinkedIn JS API to return a list of people. This list is returned as a JSON object.  Here is the call back function:

```
.result(function (result) {
        profile = result.values[0];
        // Do something with the first linkedin profile in the list...
    });
```

The object 'result' returns something like the following:

```
{"values":[{"id":"123456","firstName":"Person","lastName":"One"}, {"id":"123456","firstName":"Person","lastName":"Two"}, {"id":"123456","firstName":"Person","lastName":"Three"}],"_total":3}
```

All documentation I have seen uses this syntax to get the nth item from the result:

```
var profile = result.values[n];
```

This works well in most browsers but in IE it throws the following error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Has anybody got any idea to get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I test in IE9, and everything went well.

Comment: Are you using `profile = ...` or `var profile = ...` ?

Comment: This should work. Which IE version are you using?

Comment: @Jochem- you are correct. I was using `profile = ...` instead of `var profile = ...`. Add `var` has fixed my problem. This failed in IE7 and IE8. I can't mark your comment as correct though :(

Comment: I just tried it in IE 8 it worked fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the 'values' key is a string, the following may work (sorry, don't have IE to test):

```
var profile = result['values'][n];
```